# Why HashMap's get() returns null when it shouldn't?

Tags: java, hashmap

I wrote a method to check if a string has only unique characters. I send it the obvious non-unique-characters string `"11"` and it returns `true` instead of `false`. It happens because in the `get(c)` in `if (tab.get(c) == null)` returns `null` even though the character `'1'` is already in the HashMap.

What can I do to get the expected behavior?

```
/* Check if a string contains only unique characters */
public static boolean isUniqueChars(String s) {

    HashMap<Boolean, Character> tab = new HashMap<Boolean, Character>();
    Character c;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
        c = new Character(s.charAt(i));
        if (tab.get(c) == null)
            tab.put(Boolean.TRUE, c);
        else
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "11";
    System.out.println(isUniqueChars(s));  /* prints true! why?! */
}
```

Comment: Are you really using Boolean for the key or is that a typo?

Comment: Don't use a `HashMap`, all you need is a `HashSet`.

Comment: In addition to what Jon and Surveon said - it would be probably better to use `Set<Character>` instead of `Map<Character, Boolean>`.

Comment: You are definitely right. It's a mistake. Now I understand. Thanks!

Comment: When using a `Map` in the future, use `myMap.containsKey(keyObject)` to determine if that key is already present in the map.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're *fetching* by character, but your map's key is `Boolean`. You want the key to be `Character` and the *value* to be `Boolean`:

```
HashMap<Character, Boolean> tab = new HashMap<Character, Boolean>();
Character c;

for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
    c = new Character(s.charAt(i));
    if (tab.get(c) == null)
        tab.put(c, Boolean.TRUE);
    else
        return false;
}
return true;
```

Having said that:

- You don't need to create a new `Character` explicitly. Boxing will do that for you.
- Using a `HashSet<Character>` to keep track of the characters you've seen so far would be simpler.

For example:

```
Set<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    Character c = s.charAt(i);
    // add returns true if the element was added (i.e. it's new) and false
    // otherwise (we've seen this character before)
    if (!set.add(c)) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Comment: Is Set the same as HashSet?

Comment: @Blam: Oops, meant to use `HashSet` as the implementation, but `Set` for the variable. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you are doing a get on "value" not key.so try reversing your hashmap as

```
HashMap<Character,Boolean> tab = new HashMap<Character, Boolean>();
```

then do get the same way you are doing    tab.get(c).